# Creating Value Objects in ngModelController parsers?

Tags: angularjs, parsing, angular-ngmodel

## Background

AngularJS' [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) includes the ability to register:

- Parsers: transform the raw form field values before they are passed to the validation chain.
- Validators: pass/fail depending on the value from the parser chain.
- Formatters: can transform the model value for output in the form field

All of the examples I have seen use these to perform trivial text manipulation on the fields. eg. store an uppercased version of a text field in the model while displaying a lower cased version in the view.

The most sophisticated example I've come across transforms an input made of 3 fields into a single "date" string. But, the end result is still a string.

It seems that the parser chain could be used to create actual domain specific value object instances, not just strings. This could be used to centralise the validation logic and fix the duplication that often occurs between "model" and "form" (or, is left out of the model entirely, because it is made the forms responsibility). And keeps strings "at the boundary" of the system.

## Question

So, is returning object instances a common practice that I just haven't come across? and if not, is there a reason it's a bad idea?

Comment: I think returning domain objects is *NOT* a bad idea. However there is few case that one domain object is made of one input value. So we might have not seen an example of creating domain objects in parsers. Although I forgot where it is, I've ever seen the code in which creating Date object in parser. I think there is no difference between Date object and original domain objects.

Comment: You're right, Domain Object's is probably too broad a description. I was thinking more specifically of Value Objects. Updated, thanks.